# php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known

Tags: php, mysqli

```
   $host="localhost"; 

   $username="root";

   $password="Codiro004";

    $db="registration";

   $conn=mysqli_connect('$host','$username','$password','$db');
```

and im chekcing the connection:

```
    if($conn)
   {
    $q="Insert into 
 membership_registration  ('Name','Father_Name','Occupation','Native_Place','Email_Id','Password','Phone','Complete_Address')
          values('$Uname','$Fname','$Uoccupation','$Uplace','$Uemail',
     '$Upwd','$Uphn','$Uaddress')";

     $insert=mysqli_query($conn,$q);

      }
```

Sorry for not specifing properly bcoz im new to this
and **thanks in advance**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connect statement

```
mysqli_connect('$host','$username','$password','$db');
```

needs to be changed to

```
mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$db);
```

Because you used `'$host'` it is *literally* passed `$host` as a string into the function, if you had of used `"$host"` you would have been ok, but the quotes are ultimatly redundant in this instance.